# How to fix Attribute ambiguity

Tags: c#, attributes, ambiguity

In c#, attributes named `SomethingAttribute` can be used with the name `Something` or `SomethingAttribute`.

It's lead to an ambiguity when there are two different attributes named `SomethingAttribute` and `SomethingAttributeAttribute`, what does `SomethingAttribute` stand for ?

Example:

```
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

class MyAttributeAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[MyAttribute]  // Here an ambiguous reference.
class A
{

}
```

I can use `[My]` or `[MyAttributeAttribute]` to be sure I use the first or second attribute.

But what if I add a third attribute named `MyAttributeAttributeAttribute` ?

Comment: Why would you ever name something AttributeAttributeAttribute?

Comment: Because nobody tell me I can't ;o) and it's fun because it brakes ReSharper (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-440119). Also, the second I discover this language capability (use `[My]` instead of `[MyAttribute]`), this question pop in my mind. It takes me time to figure out the solution. I think other people can ask them-self this question so I help a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the @-quoted verbatim.

```
[@MyAttribute]
[@MyAttributeAttribute]
[@MyAttributeAttributeAttribute]
class Test
{
}
```

You can also *rename* them with `using` :

```
using Attribute1 = MyAttribute;
using Attribute2 = MyAttributeAttribute;
using Attribute3 = MyAttributeAttributeAttribute;

...

[Attribute1]
[Attribute2]
[Attribute3]
class Test
{

}
```